# Cannot set database password on MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to set up the database password on an MS Access file (.accdb), and I keep getting the error message telling me to open the database in exclusive mode, even when I *do* open it in exclusive mode. I've exhausted my usual troubleshooting options (turn the computer off and then turn it on again) so I turn to Stack Overflow for help!

Comment: To be explicit, are you using the following steps to open the database?
1. On the File tab, click Open.
2. In the Open dialog box, browse to the file that you want to open, and then select the file.
3. Click the down-arrow next to the Open button, and then click Open Exclusive.

Comment: Yes - exactly that.

Comment: Is this database only on your workstation, or a server where other users can get access to it? If only your workstation, close Access then use Explorer to look in the database folder to see if there is a .ldb / .laccdb. If so, delete it, then try again. In a multi-user environment, then your job gets a lot harder trying to find if someone else has it open.  Sometimes an MSAccess task can 'hang around' without you knowing... should show in Task Manager, or just reboot your PC.